# iOS Users Forced to Re-Authenticate in Facebook In-App Browser

Tags: authentication, cookies, facebook-browser

We are facing an issue where certain iOS users of the Facebook app have to sign in to our newspaper site every time they open a new article in the Facebook in-app browser. This issue is so rare that we have never been able to reproduce it on our own iOS devices.

Our current hypothesis is that the authentication cookie is not being retained across sessions, thereby forcing users to sign in again every time they close and reopen the Facebook in-app browser. However, we're struggling to find others experiencing the same issue, leading us to consider alternative explanations.

**Cookie Information**

- Cookie Name: nrs_id
- Domain: [www.dypnytt.no](http://www.dypnytt.no)
- Path: /
- Expires: 2023-11-23T17:03:05.743Z
- Size: 150
- SameSite: Blank

We now try a backup option, where we store the cookie in local storage if the website runs within the in-app Facebook browser. Then using it to set the cookie again. We are still awaiting user feedback whether this fixed the issue.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.